# how to refer to a function when unit testing with NodeJS / Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I'm making my first test with Mocha.

Dummy test is passing, but when I want to refer to my actual function that is in another file, it won't find it:

```
ReferenceError: main is not defined
```

I have a single index.js with :

```
async function main() {
    function comparer(otherArray) {
        return function (current) {
            return otherArray.filter(function (other) {
                return other.prm === current.prm && other.conso_prod === current.conso_prod
            }).length === 0;
        }
    }
}

module.exports = main();
```

and in my test.js file, I do:

```
const {expect} = require('chai');

describe('Sum numbers', () => {
    it('Compare 2 existing array', () => {
        const meters = []
        const perimeter = []
        const onlyInMeters = meters.filter(main.comparer(perimeter));
        expect(onlyInMeters).to.equal([]);
    });
});
```

But when I refer to `main.comparer`, it can't find it:

```
ReferenceError: main is not defined
```

What am I forgetting? Sorry, I'm a NodeJS Noob!

Comment: main() returns undefined currently -> thus exports undefined, in your test you dont import/ require main? i guess you wanted main(){ return {comparer: function...}}

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you did not import the `index.js` file in `test.js` file. You are returning noting from main function as well.

Also, why are you exporting it like `module.exports = main();` Instead you can do this:

```
// index.js
module.exports = {
  comparer: (otherArray) => { ... }
}

// test.js
cosnt main = require('PATH_OF_index.js');
main.comparer();
```

Comment: It seems to work, but when I require ../index.js, my whole code is executed...

Comment: ahhh okkkk! let me try

Comment: Ok. my whole code was executed because I had main().then(r => r); in it.

Comment: @Juliatzin Your main function is a synchronous function. You don't need async in front of it.

Comment: Yes I do, it has webservices calls, I just simplified it for the example. Thanks for the comment